# Retrieving No. of rows being Written to CSV File

Tags: sql-server, csv, t-sql, ssis, ssms

I have a task where I need to generate a CSV file from data coming out of two views including a Header having hard coded values and a Trailer at the bottom of the CSV file having These fields- Record_Type = E99, Row_count, and Blank field with 190 length.

I'm able to get the desired output file but I am not able to figure out how to retrieve the NO. of rows coming out of the two vies and write it in between the record type and the blank field at the bottom of the CSV as the whole line is trailer with | delimited.

Please help me figure this out.

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain how you are doing it now so we can suggest where to fit in the enhancement you're after. For example you could use something like this: `select 'E99|' +cast((select count(*) from view1) + (select count(*) from view2) as varchar(10))+ '|'`

Comment: I'm using SSIS 2016  for this,I've created a View for the header and a separate view for the trailer record, with hard coded values , i have given count (1) in the trailer view against the row count. I am getting the trailer with the expected out put, But do I need the views really? or can i just populate the header and trailer records when the package runs(without the views )??

Comment: You can of course type the SQL straight into the source component. It just depends how you want to slice it up

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

1. I assume you are using the SSIS Package to solve this problem.
2. Create a SQL Staging table to store the content which you want to export in CSV file. You may use stored procedure to truncate and refill this staging table by executing it. Execute this store procedure through Execute SQL Task in SSIS Package
3. Use Data Flow Task to export the data from staging table to CSV file. Input will be SQL Staging table and output will be flat file with Comma(,) delimiter.

I hope it will help you

Comment: Bro,This is not what i'm looking for.